# Touble with relevel variables in ggplot

Tags: r

I have done this:

```
FSH_date$BATCH <- relevel(FSH_date$BATCH, "0050820", "0060820", "0070820",
                          "0080820", "0090820", "0101120", "0111120", "0121320",
                          "0131320", "0010121", "0020121", "0030121", "0040721",
                          "0050721", "0060921", "0070921", "0081021", "0091021",
                          "0101121", "0010122", "0020122", "0030122")
```

I hoped to get such strict order of factor's level to scatter points but instead I got this output:

```
levels(FSH_date$BATCH)
 [1] "0050820" "0010121" "0010122" "0020121" "0020122" "0030121" "0030122" "0040721"
 [9] "0050721" "0060820" "0060921" "0070820" "0070921" "0081021" "0090820" "0091021"
[17] "0101120" "0101121" "0111120" "0121220" "0131220" "0131224" "0131225" "0131231"
[25] "0131234" "0131237" "0131243"
```

The order is not that I've been expecting and scatter is not correct as result. Could anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: It might help if you include the contents of `FSH_date$BATCH` include the output of `dput(FSH_date$BATCH)` and the code used to generate the plot so that the problem is explicitly stated in a reproducible question [MRE] may be useful

Answer (score 0):

Peter, thanks for answer.

the levels of factor in my output as not follow order that I set with relevel function  and it makes problem to sort my date in right way.

Comment: Additional comments or questions should be left as a 'comment' instead of posting an 'answer'. Please copy your 'answer' and instead leave a 'comment' in order for the community to efficiently be able to reply to you.

Comment: 0


Peter, thanks for answer.

the levels of factor in my output as not follow order that I set with relevel function and it makes problem to sort my date in right way.

Answer (score 0):

relevel() only moves one specified level to the top, and all the others one position down.
To change the order of all levels as desired, try this:

`factor(FSH_date$BATCH, levels = c("0050820", "0060820", "0070820", "0080820", "0090820", "0101120", "0111120", "0121320", "0131320", "0010121", "0020121", "0030121", "0040721", "0050721", "0060921", "0070921", "0081021", "0091021", "0101121", "0010122", "0020122", "0030122"))`

Comment: Thanks for help. Unfortunately it was not going on. After doing yours code the scatter diagram started with 0010121, 0010122, ... instead 0050820, 0060820...